# Custom routing in MVC for calling the same controller by using different names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, url-routing

My problem is that I want to call my same `Admin` controller for two different purposes.

- When I call `Admin/Index`: It works fine.
- When I call `Merchant/Index`: It also works fine.
- **But, when I call `Admin/Page1`**: It shows the `URL` as `Merchant/Page1`. I am expecting it to be `Admin/Page1`.

**Here is my RouteConfig.cs:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "MultipleUrls",
            "Merchants/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = "" });
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you call Admin/Page1 ?

Comment: Hi, I want to use Admin Controller for Both Admin As well as Merchants Portal. I want two different url's As When Admin Call It should be Admin/xyz page and For Merchants it should be Merchants/xyz. Is it possible??

Comment: That's all possible. How do you call your controller's action ? Please provide your code (edit your question).

Comment: http://localhost:50193/Admin/Index using this url(this is my login page for Admin) and   http://localhost:50193/Merchant/index using this url(this is my login page for Merchant) and want   http://localhost:50193/Admin/Dashboard after Admin Login and http://localhost:50193/Merchant/Dashboard after Merchant Login Here is Index Post action last line  return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs